# Display files and folders name from res/raw folder

Tags: android, listview, directory, names

Is there any way to get the files and folders name from **res/raw** folder.
I want to display the names in a **ListView**. After that Once I click the one of the item in a list, content of the file should come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the asset manager:

these links might be useful:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/

Comment: It is about asset folder not the raw folder?

Comment: I meant that the question is how to read res/raw folder files instead of assetes folder files?! The links you provided was about `AssetManager` that is used for asset folder!